# a simple function works correctly but also shows up undefined error message

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to this JavaScript. and I am getting this undefine error message...
Could anyone please help me out thank you.

The code is shown as below. Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>
  <p id="demo3"></p>

  <script>
    xx = "";

    function myFunction3(xx) {
      return document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = document.write(xx);
    }
    myFunction3("heheheh")
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Running that code does not give any error

Comment: Just delete `xx = "";` from your code.

Comment: `document.write` will return `undefined`, you don't need it in this case

Answer (score 2):

Why U use `document.write(xx);` ?

Try:

```
   function myFunction3(xx) {
      document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = xx;
    }
```

Comment: that's not addressing the OP's question, which is "why does my function return undefined". It's because `document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = xx;` evaluates to undefined. The return statement is not needed.

Comment: @ArthurBoucher that's not his question and also this is not the part that prints undefined.

Comment: `document.write(...)` writes the actual content, but does not return anything. So by assigning the result of a void method to the innerHTML of demo3, it prints `undefined` in it. Just inspect the elements and you will see that the `ehehehe` part is not actually **inside** the demo3 element

Comment: @MauriceNino It's half of his question. Of course replacing the `document.write(xx)` by `xx` solves the bigger problem, but where do you think the undefined "error message" comes from if not from the return statement ?

Comment: It's not even close to his question, because if the function returns undefined or not is completely irrelevant to the problem. The "error message" comes from (as I previously said) from the `innerHTML = void`. @ArthurBoucher

Answer (score 1):

you dont need `document.write` and `xx = "";` in your code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>
  <p id="demo3"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction3(xx) {
      return document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = xx;
    }
    myFunction3("heheheh")
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.write() simply assign the xx to inner HTML of demo paragraph.

```
xx = "";
function myFunction3(xx) {
    return document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = xx;
}
myFunction3("heheheh")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to write the contents of the variable xx inside of your

tag.
What you need is simply

```
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = xx;
```

This expression mutates the document but it evaluates to undefined, i.e. it doesn't return anything. Therefore your return statement also return undefined. You do not need the return statement.

Just use

```
function myFunction3(xx) {
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = xx;
}
```